# How do I generate the vendor.css and vendor.js file?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, asp.net-core, package

I have deleted the content of dist folder and now I cannot regenerate the vendor.css and .js file.

When I build there is no css being served from the server, the file empty.

This is my webpack.config.vendor.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = (env) => {
    const extractCSS = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendor.css');
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    return [{
        stats: { modules: false },
        resolve: {
            extensions: [ '.js' ]
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, use: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
                { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, use: extractCSS.extract([ isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ]) }
            ]
        },
        entry: {
            vendor: ['bootstrap', 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css', 'event-source-polyfill', 'isomorphic-fetch', 'react', 'react-dom', 'react-router-dom', 'jquery'],
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist'),
            publicPath: 'dist/',
            filename: '[name].js',
            library: '[name]_[hash]',
        },
        plugins: [
            extractCSS,
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }), // Maps these identifiers to the jQuery package (because Bootstrap expects it to be a global variable)
            new webpack.DllPlugin({
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'wwwroot', 'dist', '[name]-manifest.json'),
                name: '[name]_[hash]'
            }),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                'process.env.NODE_ENV': isDevBuild ? '"development"' : '"production"'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
        ])
    }];
};
```

I have added the below script in the package.json

```
"scripts": {
        "build": "npm install && npm run webpack",
        "webpack": "webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js"
    }
```

How do I generate the vendor.css and vendor.js file?

Comment: post your webpack.config.vendor.js too. And why you bundling vendors separate from the main application?

Comment: @MatheusSilva Added. I was trying to to find ways to build the vendor.css

Comment: @MatheusSilvav What do you suggest?